# How to print bibliography using natbib?

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I am new to Latex but I want to write my master's thesis using it.
The official requirement for reference style is the one used in Operations Research published by INFORMS. 
So I found a template of it on ShareLatex and copied the code regarding natbib to my own tex file.

I can't figure out why the reference list isn't printed using the natbib package.
Can someone please help? 
I have already spent four hours googling this and still no answer.

I use TeXStudio and when I run the file, it tells me that there are undefined citations. Basically, none of my citations show in the text. And there's no reference section either.

My tex file looks like this:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{ormsy080}
 \bibpunct[, ]{(}{)}{,}{a}{}{,}%
 \def\bibfont{\small}%
 \def\bibsep{\smallskipamount}%
 \def\bibhang{24pt}%
 \def\newblock{\ }%
 \def\BIBand{and}%}

\begin{document}
\citet{Chenetal2016}
\citep{Fildesetal2009}
\bibliography{AA}

\end{document}
```

I have a bib file saved in the same folder as my tex file and it's named AA. Here are the two bib entries I was trying to cite.

```
@Article{Chenetal2016,
  author    = {Daniel L. Chen and Martin Schonger and Chris Wickens},
  title     = {{oTree}{\textemdash}An open-source platform},
  journal   = {Journal of Behavioral and Experimental Finance},
  year      = {2016},
  volume    = {9},
  month     = {mar},
  pages     = {88--97},
  doi       = {10.1016/j.jbef.2015.12.001},
  abstract  = {[B]},
  keywords  = {rank4},
  publisher = {Elsevier {BV}},
}
```

and

```
@Article{Fildesetal2009,
  author    = {R. Fildes and P. Goodwin and M. Lawrence and K. Nikolopoulos},
  title     = {Effective forecasting and judgmental adjustments},
  journal   = {International Journal of Forecasting},
  year      = {2009},
  volume    = {25},
  number    = {1},
  month     = {jan},
  pages     = {3--23},
  doi       = {10.1016/j.ijforecast.2008.11.010},
  abstract  = {[A]},
  publisher = {Elsevier {BV}},
}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Assuming you have the file `ormsy080.bib`, you have tom compile `pdflatex`, then `bibtex`, then `pdflatex` twice and it should work. If you are getting **? (?)** as output then either: a) you don't have `ormsy080.bib` or; b) you aren't compiling `bibtex`.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Thanks for your explanation. I didn't have the ormsy080.bst. But I just downloaded it from sharelatex now. And for compile, the only way I know how to compile so far is to click the green compile button in TexStudio while my .tex file is opened...

Comment: @Michelle TeXStudio should automatically run BibTeX, so once you have the `ormsy080.bst` (sorry, in my first comment I said `ormsy080.bib`) it should compile correctly.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Thanks a lot! It worked!! Awesome. and I changed \bibliographystyle{ormsy080} into ormsv080 as Kurt suggested!

Comment: @Michelle Great! Just a tip for the future: When your bibliography does not appear take a look in the .blg file. It will contain the log generated by bibtex. LaTeX IDEs are surprisingly bad at reading the .blg file. For example, when I compiled your file I got: `I couldn't open style file ormsy080.bst
---line 2 of file test.aux
 : \bibstyle{ormsy080
 :                   }
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command`. This will help you debug your bibliography.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Thanks for this tip. Does the .blg file only shows if there's a compile error? Because with compilation ending normally, right now I see only bbl, aux and pdf files.

Comment: @Michelle no, the .blg shows the whole bibtex log. If you don't have it, probably TeXStudio is deleting it. A .blg should look like [this](https://pastebin.com/z2d6vgi7).

Answer (score 1):

My bibliography now prints out as wanted after I did the following:

1. download the bst file specified in \bibliographystyle{}
2. make sure the name of the bst file corresponds to what is inside the \bibliographystyle{}
3. using TeXStudio, simply click on compile.